# Which building is shown on p. 159 of "Roma descritta ed illustrata" (seconda edizione)?

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture

On Wikimedia Commons, the following [illustration of a building presumably located in Rome is shown](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:159_of_%27Roma_descritta_ed_illustrata._Seconda_edizione%27_(11000343164).jpg)  ("p. 159" refers to the pagination of the source PDF file, see below):

[image: 159 of 'Roma descritta ed illustrata. Seconda edizione]

<sup>Source: The British Library, No restrictions, via Wikimedia Commons"</sup>

The illustration's source is ["Roma descritta ed illustrata. Seconda edizione"](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?cs=frb&doc=BLL01001529989&dscnt=1&scp.scps=scope:(BLCONTENT)&frbg=&tab=local_tab&srt=rank&ct=search&mode=Basic&dum=true&tb=t&indx=1&vl(freeText0)=001529989&fn=search&vid=BLVU1) by the italian archaeologist [Giuseppe Antonio Guattani](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Antonio_Guattani). The British Library offers a [complete PDF download of the book](http://access.bl.uk/item/pdf/lsidyv35ea090a). The illustration can be found in chapter V "Monte Capitolino, e sue adjacenze" (starting at p. 121 of the PDF, p. 73 by the book's page number).

To properly categorize the illustration on Wikimedia Commons, I need to identify the building. But as far as I see, the book doesn't disclose which building on the Capitoline hill is shown here. I've looked for similar illustrations in vain and even asked an archaeologist who lives in Rome since 20 years but even he wasn't able to identify the building.

The building might be located outside of Rome, since the book also has illustrations of other buildings included if the fit the subject, e.g. on page 138 of the PDF, there's [an illustration of the Roman theater at Otricoli](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:138_of_%27Roma_descritta_ed_illustrata._Seconda_edizione%27_(11000127995).jpg) in comparison to the [Teatro di Marcello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatre_of_Marcellus).

Is anyone able to identify the building shown in the illustration above?

Comment: Is it possible that he describes his own reconstruction of the original Tabularium (plus scuderia senatore below)? That building was heavily modified over time, has a description following that pic, and even roughly matching it (pic inded worth a thousand words;) and a seemingly wild signifier attached ("n2", p99) that may be the internal link?

Comment: I think the "n 2" on p.99 is a signature mark. See "a 2" on p.3, "e 2" on p.35, "m 2" on p91, and so on.  They recur every 8 pages; the book is evidently a quarto.  (4 leaves per signature, so 8 pages.)